# Basic circuit diagram question when current isn't given

Tags: circuit-analysis

How do you calculate the voltage in a diagram when only resistances are given? The question I'm looking at is: 
[image]

How is V2 6? I used KCL and KVL and couldn't solve the system of equations because there was not enough info

Comment: Because 3ohm||2ohm=6/5ohm.

Comment: Can you explain what the || means?

Comment: It's the operator used to indicate impedances in parallel.

Comment: Guess what two parallel lines means! 3 ohm in parallel with 2 ohms.

Comment: You're trying to solve this the hard way.  There are two resistors in parallel.  Calculate their equivalent resistance, then you just have a voltage divider.

Comment: Apparently the OP failed the basic class of introduction to electricity. If such misunderstanding exists at this level, a change in stride should be strongly advised.

Comment: If source is 16V@ 2Ω and load is 1.2 Ω then load voltage V2=16V* 1.2Ω /(2+1.2)Ω=6V ok?

Answer (score 1):

3||2 = (1/3+1/2)^-1 = 6/5
Voltage divider after that:
V2 = 16*(6/5 / (6/5+2)) = 6

This works because V2 is the same for the 2 and 3 ohm in parallel. Therefore you combine the two in parallel. Now there's a 2 resistor voltage divider between 6/5 ohms and 2 ohms.

If you want to do this the more basic way, after combining 3 and 2 in parallel, you would combine that with the to to get 2+6/5 ohms. 16 volts going into that would give you the current (5amps) through the series 2 ohms. 2 ohms times the current would give you the voltage on that half (10V) and 16V - that voltage would give you the voltage on the other side.